# How to remove entries in a database past a certain number

Tags: mysql, sql

I have about 110,000,000 entries in a mysql database. I would like to limit it to exactly 100M entries. How I was thinking of doing it was in three steps:

1. Create a new table
2. Insert into the new table with a `INSERT...SELECT...LIMIT 100000000`.
3. Delete the old table and rename the new table.

Is there a way to do this with a `DELETE` query instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the best way would be with two queries: First, to get the count, then to remove the correct number of rows. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t
/* 110,000,000 */
DELETE FROM t LIMIT 10000 /* (110,000,000 - 100,000,000 = 10,000) */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact number, you could delete the rows:

```
delete t from t
    limit 10000000;
```

However, it is probably faster to use your approach.

Comment: The above would delete 100M rows, or keep 100M rows?

Comment: The above would delete 10,000,000 rows.

Comment: @David542 But which rows it deletes is anyone's guess

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but it sounds like this is what you want:

`DELETE FROM tbn_name LIMIT 100000000 - ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_name )`

Comment: Can you be more specific? Did you get an error? Some other message? What was the end result?